Calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^7} \, dx$
Calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^7} \, dx$
This showed up on a complex analysis qualification exam. First, I will write
$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{1+x^7} \, dx = \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac{x^2}{1+x^7} \, dx $$
Now, if $\frac{x^2}{1+x^7}$  were even, I would write the above as half of the integral from $-R$ to $R$ and then create a semicircular arc $C_R$, use Jordan's lemma to show that it vanishes, and then get the result. But $\frac{x^2}{1+x^7}$ is not even (nor odd). What can be done here to sidestep this issue? (I'm open to the use of monotone/dominated/bounded convergence theorems as well if that's easier)

It would be better to use a keyhole contour, but substitute $y=x^7$ first. If your heart's set on a semicircle, use $y=x^{7/2}$ instead.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/42969

\begin{align}
\color{#44f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2} \over 1 + x^{7}}{\rm d}x} & =
{1 \over 7}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-4/7} \over 1 + x}{\rm d}x =
{1 \over 7}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{3/7 - 1} \over \left(1 + x\right)^{3/7 + 4/7}}{\rm d}x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 7}\,{\Gamma\left(3/7\right)\Gamma\left(4/7\right) \over
\Gamma\left(3/7 + 4/7\right)}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#44f}{\large{1 \over 7}\,\pi\csc\left(3\pi \over 7\right)} \approx 0.4603
\end{align}
See this link.
